# SSRS: Trying to Filter a Textbox/Report Item

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, postgresql-9.1, reportbuilder3.0

I have calculated the % between 2 numbers using an expression in a table.

I want to only filter the results that are below -20%

I have tried going to 'Tablix Properties' -> 'Filters' and then input

'Expression: TextBox34' (Text)

'Operator: <'

'Value: -0.2'

I cant get any results, is it possible to filter an Expression?

Im using Visual Studio 10, and PostgreSQL 9.2

**Update 12 July - To throw more light onto my problem.**

I'm calculating the 12 month average sales, and the most recent 2 months average sales. With these 2 numbers, im going to calculate the percentage to see which customers orders have dropped in the past 2 months.

In order to get the numbers of the 12mth-avg-sales and 2mth-avg-sales i actually created 2 separate tables-matrix.

I then created another table and then used LookUp so that both 12mth-avg-sales and 2mth-avg-sales are in the same table.

So now the Main table looks like this

```
|Customers|12mth-avg-sales|2mth-avg-sales|Percentage|
```

As you can imagine, both 12mth and 2mth avg sales are both expressions.

And to calculcate the Percentage is also an expression.

I'm hoping to filter the Percentage to show only those below 20%... Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You should set up a filter similar to this:

[image]

The most important thing to note is that this is **not** referring to a textbox but to a field in the table dataset.

Depending on your underlying data types you may have to tweak this.

Example data without filter:

[image]

With filter:

[image]

Comment: Hey Ian, thanks for the reply. I'm not sure how i can tweak the data so it becomes a value. Let me edit my question to throw more light on it